# What is the location of x and y

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the location of x and y in this array:

```
var a = [ [1,2], [x], [3, [y]] ];
```

I'm a bit confused about the syntax here.
Would it be:

```
a[1] = x and a[2][1] = y?
```

Or does the introduction of a new set of square brackets mean we instead have:

```
a[1][0] = x and a[2][1][0] = y?
```

Comment: `a[1][0] = x` and `a[2][1][0] = y`, note it starts at `0` not `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's find out together ;)

```
var a = [ [1,2], [x], [3,[y]]];
```

if you write that line by line:

```
var a = [
  [1,2],   // new array with index 0 containing 1 and 2 => a[0][0] = 1 and a[0][1] = 2
  [x],     // new array with index 1 containing x => a[1][0] = x
  [3,[y]]  // new array with index 2 containing 3 and array containing y a[2][0] = 3 a[2][1][0] = y 
];
```

in other words, x = a[1][0]

Comment: Thanks! Feel a bit dumb for forgetting to start my index from 0 though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = "x";
var y = "y";
var a = [ [1,2], [x], [3, [y]] ];

console.log(a[1][0]);
console.log(a[2][1][0]);
```